# Hiding comments with hs-hide-level in Emacs hide-show mode

Tags: emacs, folding, code-folding

When I use hs-hide-level, it only hides code blocks at at the current level, but leaves comment blocks at the same level open.  For example, if I take the following un-folded code:

```
top level code {
    /* Level 2
     * Multi-line
     * Comment
     */
    level 2 code block {
        Code inside
        level 2
        block
    }
}
```

And I use the hs-hide-level inside the top-level block, I will get

```
top level code {
    /* Level 2
     * Multi-line
     * Comment
     */
    level 2 code block { ... }
}
```

but I want

```
top level code {
    /* Level 2 ... 
    level 2 code block {...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this feature only appeared since the question was asked, but there is the option `hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all`, which according to the documentation does this:

> Hide the comments too when you do an `hs-hide-all`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question directly, but it might help nevertheless.

You can use library [**`hide-comnt.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hide-comnt.el) to hide only comments.
The description is [**here**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HideOrIgnoreComments).

You can hide comments interactively or using Lisp macro `with-comments-hidden`.  The effect of both is controlled by option `ignore-comments-flag`, which gives you additional control over the behavior.

Command `hide/show-comments` acts on the active region, or the whole buffer if the region is not active.